# How to process files sequentially?

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have approximately 1000 files in local drive.I need to move that files into SQL Server accordingly one after another.

Since local drive having files like `file1.csv,file2.csv,..upto file1000.csv`.I am sure that number of files in local drive may change dynamically.

I can able to created template for move that files into SQL Server.But i have to process the file2 when file 1 has been completely moved into SQL Server.

Is this possible in NiFi without using Wait\Notify processor?

can anyone please guide me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EnforceOrder Processor to process files sequentially available in NiFi-1.2.0.bin.

https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/7e6158460cfcb0b5911acefbb455edf0

Answer (score -1):

There is a `Concurrent Tasks` property in processors.
If you will set 1 in each processor they will run sequentially.

But maybe it's better to insert all the files into temp table and then run aggregation on the level of database?